# Get seperate keys and values from string where all data is inline

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, string

I am using a Custom Meta Box Class for adding meta boxes in Wordpress.
One of the fields I am using is a repeater field to add multiple blocks of the same fields to one post.

When I retrieve the data, all the keys and values are combined inside one string. See this screenshot:
[image]

Inside `slide_re_` you can see the keys and values with a lot of different characters added.
What I need from this string is

```
'slide_text_field_title => 'Slide 1'
```

and the rest of the values.

How could I extract or filter this data from this string?

Comment: that's a serialized array. you need to `unserialize($array['slider_re_'])`

Comment: @AlexTartan this gave me exactly what I needed, thank you. I did not recognize it as a serialized array. If you want to create an answer for this question, I will accept it.

Comment: Sure thing, Ted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there is a serialized array.

To convert it back to an array, use:

```
unserialize($array['slide_re_'])
```